# How to create a separate directory for cordova app and storing data in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, cordova-plugins

I want to create a specific directory for my cordova project. I have no idea what to do for that.
I refered so may links like,
[How to move file to app directory cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27765007/how-to-move-file-to-app-directory-cordova)

[cordova, android app how to create subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826517/cordova-android-app-how-to-create-subfolder)
 and someother links.
But it is not clear whether they are using any cordova plugins for this or we can do with pure javascript. These are not working for me.
Please suggest if any plugins or functions are available.

Thanks.

Comment: Try showing some code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use this plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file

I don't know what version of cordova do you use and if this plugin was updated, but when I use it, it doesn't work with WindowsPhone. Ok for Android and iOS.

To get file system:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, downloadFile, fileSystemFail);
```

Donwload file function:

```
downloadFile: function(fileSystem){
    // your code
}
```

---

To create a directory:

```
var directoryEntry = fileSystem.root;
var folderName = "Folder";

directoryEntry.getDirectory(folderName, { create: true, exclusive: false }, onDirectorySuccess, onDirectoryFail);
```

Where `onDirectorySuccess` and `onDirectoryFail` are functions like:

```
onDirectorySuccess: function(parent){
    console.log(parent);
},
onDirectoryFail: function(error){
    console.log("Unable to create new directory: " + error.code);
}
```

---

To get path of file in the directory:

```
var filePath = directoryEntry.toURL() + "/" + folderName + "/" + fileName;
```

And to get file:

```
directoryEntry.getFile(folderName + "/" + fileName, { create: true, exclusive: false }, onFileSuccess, onFileFail);
```

---

To delete a file first you need to get it:

```
directoryEntry.getFile(folderName + "/" + fileName, { create: true, exclusive: false }, onFileSuccessRemove, onFileFail);
```

Then in success function:

```
function onFileSuccessRemove(entry) {
    entry.remove();
}
```

---

My application was with file download, so this is code to save a file in a directory:

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
fileTransfer.download(URL, filePath, downloadComplete, downloadFail, true);
```

It's not your case but I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes. I read about it. But documentation is with a bit of confusion.

Comment: Are those directories are created already ? And how to write files into that directories?

Comment: An error occured, which is `LocalFileSystem` undefined

Comment: Before that line I have this piece of code `window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;`. Maybe it can solve. Have you import correctly the plugin?

Comment: Fine, but now `fileSystem` is undefined.

Comment: Is your success function correct? You can also try: `window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) { /* code here */ }, function(evt){ });`

Comment: How to remove file from the directory?

Comment: I tried it. It is not removing the file. I'am using jQuery. I think jQuery function overrides remove function. What to do? I used `create: false` instead of `create: true`. Is it wrong?

Comment: I also use jQuery. Have you try in this way? `directoryEntry.getFile(folderName + "/" + fileName, { create: true, exclusive: false }, function onFileSuccessRemove(entry) { entry.remove(); }, onFileFail);` Have you any error?

Comment: Have you initializate it?

Comment: How to initialize directoryEntry?

Comment: ` var directoryEntry = fileSystem.root;` see my code above :-)

Comment: Yes. Used. OK. I will try it.If you know any thing else, help me please.

Comment: Can we use remove for PERSISTENT FileSystem ?

Comment: I mean, can we remove file from persistent storage