# Ionic Cordova file plugin premission denied

Tags: android, cordova, pdf, permissions, ionic-framework

I am having this issue: My app (Android version) downloads PDF files and saves them to cordova.file.dataDirectory. User can then open or send PDF files via native apps (like adobe reader and gmail). Here lies my problem...when I want to attach pdf to gmail or open pdf in adobe app I get message (it pop on screen) that gmail ( or acrobat) doesnt have permission to open my pdf. In documentation for cordova file plugin it's stated that this dataDirectory is under "private". But only other non-private folder is on SD card, but not every phone have this card so this is not solution. Is there any way to solve this? Can I create folder with no restricting permissions on folder and just save my pdf-s in thah folder?

I made this app around 1 year ago and now I want to do some updates and now I have this issues with permissions (I didnt have them with my old build. User could view and send files as much as they want no matter what Android OS they were using).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [cordova-plugin-file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) for creating directory.

Use following code for creating a new directory in device.
If the given code executed properly then it will create a directory at the root of the file system.

```
window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
  var entry = fileSystem.root;
  entry.getDirectory("Directory_Name", { // Give your directory name instead of Directory_Name
    create: true,
    exclusive: false
  },onSuccess, onFail);
},null);

// onSuccess function for creating directory
 function onSuccess(parent) {
   dirPath = parent.nativeURL; // It will return location of the folder in device
   console.log(dirPath);
 }

// onFail function for creating directory
function onFail(error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

[Follow SO referred link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35056472/how-to-create-a-separate-directory-for-cordova-app-and-storing-data-in-it).

Comment: Will this folder and all content be available for other apps to use it? Thank you very much for replay, will check this code soon and mark your answer accordingly.